# Simulate many small IoT servers with a single server: Use NGINX 'map'?

Tags: nginx

I have a bunch of tiny servers that each serve a few live DASH/HLS streams (something like a RasPi with a USB tuner dongle).  These servers have URLs like `https://streamingX.<my_domain>/serviceY/<files>`.  I'm making a caching reverse-proxy, but I lack enough hardware to give it a real test.  So I'd like to simulate a bunch of the little systems with a single NGINX instance.

I have looped video feeding a bunch of DASH/HLS packagers that output into a file hierarchy like this: `www/streamingX/serviceY/<files>`, and am able to serve that tree just fine to simulate 50 of the small video servers.

But how do I convert URLs for the tiny servers into this file hierarchy?  That is, convert `https://streamingX.<my_domain>/serviceY/<files>` to `https://<my_domain>/streamingX/serviceY/<files>`?

My initial guess was that the NGINX `map` directive was all I needed, but the following isn't working:

```
map $host$uri $uri {
    default $uri;
    ~(streaming[0-9])\.(*)/(*) $1/$3;
}
```

What clue am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in at least two ways:

1) With `map` directive:

```
map $host $prefix {
    "~^(streaming\d{1,2})\." /$1;
}

server {
    ...
    # before "location" declarations, if any
    rewrite .* $prefix$uri last;
    ...
}
```

2) With `server_name` directive:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com "~^(?<streaming>streaming\d{1,2})\.example\.com$";
    ...
    # before "location" declarations, if any
    if ($streaming) {
        rewrite .* /$streaming$uri last;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update**

Found more elegant way to do it without `rewrite` directives:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com "~^(?<prefix>streaming\d{1,2})\.example\.com$";
    root <your_root>;

    ...

    location / {
        alias <your_root>/$prefix/;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add more detail:  The tiny servers all share common root directory content: Only URLs that start with `serviceX` *and* contain `serviceY` get a new path.  All other paths can be used as-is, ignoring the `serviceX`.

Does that make it more complex?  I could just duplicate the roots as well.  I should also mention that X and Y are numbers, with X=0..24 and Y=0..5.

Comment: If for example `streaming1` can contain only `service1` or `service2`, and `streaming2` can contain only `service3` or `service4` this requires more complex configuration. Otherwise this can be achieved by modifying regex to something like `location ~ ^/(streaming1|streaming2|streaming3)(/(?:service1|service2|service3)/.*)$ { ...`.

Comment: Since X and Y are numbers, our regex can be simplified: `location ~ ^/(streaming\d{1,2})(/service\d/.*)$ {...` .

Comment: You also have to specify a resolver that will be able to resolve any of your `streamingX.<my_domain>` domains into the IP address.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "resolver".  Is that an NGINX thing, or a DNS thing? Will my simulator need to include it's own BIND server for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that I completely misunderstood your question and give you a recipe of reverse proxying instead of simulating a bunch of servers as you needed. I'm completely rewrite my answer, please check.

Comment: Actually, I will *also* be running a caching reverse-proxy!  While the small systems can handle their video chores quite well, they are easily overwhelmed by too many TLS connections.  The simulator needs to "look like" the real hardware so I can also develop and test the caching reverse-proxy, and know it will work correctly when deployed to support real hardware.

Comment: That is another question, and there you will need a resolver which will be able to resolve all of your `streamingX.your_domain.com` subdomain names into an IP addresses. But before we go further, can you test this configuration with your simulator? Does it work?

Comment: With indexing enabled on NGINX, http://${HOSTNAME}/streaming1 shows the directory, but http://streaming1.${HOSTNAME}/ doesn't.  (Edit: Using the first method. Trying second next.)

Comment: Neither method works, but my guess is it's due to my being restricted to the LAN, using only $HOSTNAME, which seems to prevent streaming1.hostname from working.

Comment: Could it be as simple as putting "streamingX.hostname" lines in the hosts file?

Comment: That is the way I tested these configs. All `streamingX.hostname` entries must have the `hostname` IP.

Comment: Updated an answer with third method, I think this one better than two previous.

Comment: I'm getting a wildcard DNS entry added for my PC's name, so I can also test with "real" FQDN URLs.